# Add complex numbers code

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

```
class complex1   
{   
    public:
        int real,img;
        complex1(){}
        complex1(int a)
        {
            real=a;
            img=a;
        }
        complex1(int a,int b)
        {
            real=a;
            img=b;
        }

        complex1 sum(int x,complex1 y);
        complex1 sum(complex1,complex1);
        complex1 display(complex1); 
};

complex1 complex1::sum(int x,complex1 y)
{
    complex1 num;
    num.real=x+y.real;
    num.img=y.img;
    return num;
}

complex1 complex1::sum(complex1 a,complex1 b)
{
    complex1 num;
    num.real=a.real+b.real;
    num.img=a.img+b.img;
    return num;

}

complex1 complex1::display(complex1 c)
{
    cout<<"The complex number is:\n";
    cout<<c.real<<"+i"<<c.img;
}

main()
{
    complex1 p,q,r,s;
    p=complex1(2,4);
    q=complex1 (3,5);


    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"p="<<display(p);
    cout<<"q="<<display(q);
}
```

Using constructors we need to add two complex numbers. I get the error

> Error: display was not declared in this scope.

Any suggestions? where am I wrong?

Comment: Hey there, and welcome to SO! Your question will probably get closed because it doesn't present an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It also lacks the description of any research efforts you should've undertaken yourself before posting the question.

Comment: Perhaps it's not helpful, but `std::complex` would probably do everything you want. That said, `display` is a member of `complex1`, which should hint at what's gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are calling `display()` outside of an instance method implementation, without invoking it on an instance of `complex1`, so the compiler doesn't know where to find it.

You would need to call it something like `p.display(p)`.

However, you have several more serious errors here:

1. The `sum()` and `display()` methods do not do anything with `this`, and so they are acting like static methods but still require an instance.  This is confusing.  Make them static. (The `sum()` method should probably be implemented as a `+` operator overload, anyway.)
2. The `display()` method should probably be implemented as a `<<` operator overload, taking an `std::ofstream&` as the left operand, and it should return `std::ofstream&` instead of a `complex1` object.  (And in your implementation it doesn't even return a `complex1` object at all, even though it is declared to.  This is an error.)

For example, to fix the first point I would remove the `sum()` methods altogether and go with a free operator, something like this:

```
complex1 operator+(complex1 const & a, complex1 const & b)
{
    return complex1(a.real + b.real, a.img + b.img);
}
```

Since your `complex1(int)` constructor is implicitly implicit (hah!) this operator can work with `complex1 + complex1`, `complex1 + int`, and `int + complex1` automatically.  (But note that your `complex1(int)` constructor assigns the argument to both `real` and `img`, which is likely a bug; I would expect you would want to initialize `img` to zero instead.)

To fix the second issue, I would remove your `display()` method entirely and go with a free operator, something like this:

```
std::ofstream & operator<<(std::ofstream & s, complex1 const & c)
{
    return s << c.real << "+i" << c.img;
}
```

Then, to output a number you could do something like:

```
std::cout << "p=" << p;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `display` function needs to return a `complex1` object like you said it would in the class. Otherwise, you could change the stub to

```
void display(complex1);
```

Also, `display` is a **member function**, meaning it needs to be called on a class instance. You need to do

```
p.display();
```

Furthermore, instead of using your `sum` functions, you could overload the `+` operator for both `int`'s and other `complex1`'s:

```
complex1 operator+(const complex1 &c1, const complex1 &c2);
```